# Show message on click of disabled button

Tags: angular, onclick

In my angular app, I have a button with [disabled]="isDisabled()".
I want a pop up to show when the disabled button is clicked.

I've tried to overlap a span/div which would detect click and see id the button is disabled or not.

This is my code:

```
//button becomes enabled if checkbox input is checked.
<button class="btnValider" id="rgpdValider" type="submit" [disabled]="isDisabled()"> Accédez au questionnaire</button>
```

It just doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried adding a disabled class (instead of disabling the button), and then choosing the click action depending on the disabled attritbute? such as `(click)="disabled ? disabledReaction() : validerReaction()"` and your class with ``[ngClass]="{ disabled: disabled }"` and then some css for the `.disabled` class...

Answer (score 1):

> Disabled elements don't fire mouse events.

The solution is to use [ngClass] and make the button appear as if it is disabled. Here's a working example:

```
<button [ngClass]="'isDisabled()' ? 'disabled': false" (click)="alert()">Click</button>
```

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "test-app";
  disabled = true;

  alert() {
    window.alert("hi");
  }

  isDisabled() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```
.disabled {
  color: grey;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! The problem is that I don't want to change the existing code which I didn't write by myself. I'm afraid to mess up other things.